# Como sortear os itens de uma Listbox usando quicksort

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, quicksort

estou realizando um projeto para a Universidade que consiste em realizar um software que faça o 'sort' de uma listbox usando quicksort , BlubbleSort etc... Em VB.NET
Fiz um array para gerar os números aleatórios da listbox , mas minha dificuldade agora e pegar os números desta listbox para realizar o sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um laço de repetição para adicionar os dados da ListBox num array usando o método CopyTo.

Algo como:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.Count - 1
    ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(seuarray, i)
Next
seuarray.Sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

O próprio [Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do .Net Framework já traz alguma facilidade para você pois por trás ele já implementa algoritmos como QuickSort e Heapsort dependedo do tamanho do array de entrada.No pior caso a complexidade é de O(n log n)

Se a dificuldade é apenas pegar os valores do array então a a solução da Catharina já te ajuda.